# Has the ruling in the EU regarding cookies changed to include the "only necessary" choice?

Tags: eu-cookie-law

When the EU first introduced the cookie notifications, I seem to recall that web sites did pop up such notifications, but the options to disable data collection were often pretty hidden; the defaults often seemed to indicate that strict settings were in place by default (but weren't), and so on. I.e., web sites obviously complied with respect to the exact letter of the law, but still tried to do the things that the law was intended to avoid in any way possible.

Recently (since a few months?) most cookie popups directly and clearly include the option of allowing "necessary" cookies only, or sometimes even the option "no cookies". Is this due to a change of heart in the community, or have the EU laws been revised to enforce this?